# TAG Query showing only 1 result

Tags: wp-query

I need to create a query that returns all posts with a specific TAG. With the community help I was able to get to the query below but it is returning only ONE result when I have 3 posts marked with that TAG.

```
*<?php
    $casestudy_query = new WP_Query( 'tag=homepage' );

    if ( $casestudy_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $casestudy_query->have_posts() ) {
    $casestudy_query->the_post(); }} ?>

    <span class="casestudy">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </span>         *
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try an expanded query as your current query is relying on the slug of the tag.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1, //get all posts
    'post_type' => 'post', //assuming your are not using a CPT
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'tag' => 'homepage' //select your tag
        ),
     ),
);

 $casestudy_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```